# Elasticsearch error - While trying to search contents in the attachment

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Am using ingest-attachment processor plugin to index my pdf files and am able to index also using java code. Now, i want to search some contents in my pdf files which is available in elasticsearch.

Am using the below query to search contents in files and am getting error while executing this code.

```
SearchRequest contentSearchRequest = new SearchRequest(ATTACHMENT); 
SearchSourceBuilder contentSearchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
contentSearchRequest.types(TYPE);
QueryBuilder attachmentQB = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("attachment.content", "karthikeyan");
contentSearchSourceBuilder.query(attachmentQB);
contentSearchSourceBuilder.size(50);
searchRequest.source(contentSearchSourceBuilder);
SearchResponse contentSearchResponse = null;
try {
    contentSearchResponse = restHighLevelClient.search(contentSearchRequest);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.getLocalizedMessage();
}

SearchHit[] contentSearchHits = contentSearchResponse.getHits().getHits();
long contenttotalHits=contentSearchResponse.getHits().totalHits;
System.out.println("condition Total Hits --->"+contenttotalHits);

for (SearchHit contenthit : contentSearchHits) {

    Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = contenthit.getSourceAsMap();
    System.out.println("----------->"+sourceAsMap.get("resume"));
}
```

Please find the document that i have indexed

```
{
  "_index": "attach_local",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "106",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "resume": "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",
    "attachment": {
      "date": "2018-06-21T10:50:01Z",
      "content_type": "application/pdf",
      "author": "Karthikeyan A S",
      "language": "sv",
      "content": "My first Elastic Search attachment using ingest-attachment plugin. Karthikeyan",
      "content_length": 71
    },
    "postDate": "2018-06-21T10:53:53.161Z",
    "Name": "Karthikeyan"
  }
}
```

Please find the below error that am getting

```
ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed]]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestResponse.java:177)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:573)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [GET], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/attach_local/doc/_search?typed_keys=true&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&search_type=query_then_fetch&batched_reduce_size=512], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"Binary fields do not support searching","index_uuid":"JjE66zAUSKi11FJ_yHVLSA","index":"attach_local"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"attach_local","node":"uPLyU7R5RXeirg8XzRqhnA","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"Binary fields do not support searching","index_uuid":"JjE66zAUSKi11FJ_yHVLSA","index":"attach_local"}}]},"status":400}
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:357)
```

Please find my mappings details

```
PUT attach_local
{
  "mappings" : {
    "doc" : {
      "properties" : {
        "attachment" : {
          "properties" : {
            "content" : {
              "type" : "binary"
            },
            "content_length" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "content_type" : {
              "type" : "text"
            },
            "language" : {
              "type" : "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "resume" : {
          "type" : "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Am using Elasticsearch version 6.2.3 version

Comment: Change your mapping for attachment.content to text then search will work for this case. In general while using ingest attachment processor the mapping for attachment will be dynamic meaning you should let ES infer the mapping for you.

Comment: @sramalingam24 - I have changed the mappings for `content` from `binary` to `text` and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mappings has been changed as below., and it is working fine.

```
PUT attach_local
{
  "mappings" : {
    "doc" : {
      "properties" : {
        "attachment" : {
          "properties" : {
            "content" : {
              "type" : "text"
            },
            "content_length" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "content_type" : {
              "type" : "text"
            },
            "language" : {
              "type" : "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "resume" : {
          "type" : "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```